# Accessing array/object variables by key, within a handlebars mustache

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, handlebars.js, mustache

I can't seem to find a way of doing this, and have tried subexpressions and various other answers posted on StackOverflow - but they all seem to assume that I know the key I'm using in advance.

I have the following object:

```
{
    fields: {
        1: {
            complete: 1,
            submitted: 0
        },
        2: {
            complete: 1,
            submitted: 0
        }
}
```

etc. etc.

In my Handlebars template, I'm looping through an array of objects. Each object in that array has a `field_id` key which is a number that matches up to the 1 or 2 in the above example.

I need to access the variables in the above array structure, based on the current field_id being looped. I've tried:

`{{fields[(field_id)].complete}}`

`{{fields[{{field_id}}].complete}}`

`{{fields.(field_id).complete}}`

`{{fields.({{field_id}}).complete}}`

And none of them work.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Where does `field_id` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* create a custom helper for this. Instead, I would use the existing [Lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) partnered with the [with block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#with):

```
{{#with (lookup fields field_id) as |field|}}
    {{field.complete}}
{{/with}}
```

Alternatively you could use the lookup helper with a [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions):

```
{{lookup (lookup fields field_id) 'complete'}}
```

Comment: I used the latter solution here, much neater than my custom helper. Thank you muchly!

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by registering a custom helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( 'getfield', function ( data, field_id, key ) {
    var val = ( data[ field_id ] ) ? data[ field_id ][ key ] : '';
    return val;
} );
```

and then made use of this in my templates with:

```
{{getfield fields field_id 'complete'}}
```