# Handlebars - getting value of array with an index-number from another object / arrA[object.num].value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, handlebars.js

**EDIT**

Thanx to 76484!

I have added some more here to make the question clearer.

I want to access "handlungsstrang[karte[x].strang].farbe" in my handlebars and change the background color of a div.

Each "Karte" (1 - x) of a "handlungsstrang" (1,2,3) should have the same color.

I render the webpage with:

```java
   res.render("index", {
      myDoc: myInit.myDoc,
    });
```

myDoc (from a file.json - looks like this (shortened):

```
{
  "projektTitel": "Plotter Test",
  "filename": "editDoc.json",
<….>
  "dramturgiefarbe": "#00FFFF",
  "handlungsstrang": [
    {"name": "A-Strang", "beschreibung": "Heldin ermittelt den Mörder", "farbe": "#34C534", "initProzent": 50, "symbol": "A", "rausgeschoben": "false"},
    {"name": "B-Strang", "beschreibung": "Heldin ermittelt den Mörder", "farbe": "#666666", "initProzent": 30, "symbol": "B", "rausgeschoben": "false"}
  ],
  "minidisplay": {
    "sichtbar": true
    },
  "karte": [ {
      "uuid": "0",
      "farbe": "#34C534",
      "strang": 0,
      "band": 1,
      "isAnmerkungsKarte": 0
    },
    {
      "uuid": "2",
      "farbe": "#CEE960",
      "strang": 1,
      "band": 1,
      "isAnmerkungsKarte": 0
    }
    {
      "uuid": "3",
      "farbe": "#CEE960",
      "strang": 3,
      "band": 1,
      "isAnmerkungsKarte": 0
    }
  ]  
}
```

THIS WORKS in the fiddle - THANX 76484!

```
    {{#each karte}}
    {{lookup (lookup ../handlungsstrang strang) 'farbe'}}
    {{/each}}
```

And this NOT on my site:

```
<div class="papierkorbbereich">

    {{#each myDoc.karte}}
    {{@index}}
    >{{lookup (lookup ../handlungsstrang strang) 'farbe'}}<
     
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Result: 1><2><3>< …

It is exasperating. What am I doing wrong...?

### SOLUTION

I've included the solution here in case someone is looking for it and wants to get a quick answer. Here is what worked for me:

handlungsstrang[ karte[x].strang].farbe // with Handlebars:
=> {{lookup (lookup @root/myDoc/handlungsstrang strang) 'farbe'}}

```
{{#each myDoc.karte}}
    {{lookup (lookup @root/myDoc/handlungsstrang strang) 'farbe'}}
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: I think this answer addresses your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65256176/3397771. This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39311276/3397771

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! But I don't think the two references will get me anywhere. There a keyword is searched in the object by lookup. But I have to pass a number and search for an array entry. Or do I see something wrong? In the {{#each}} - loop I get also from the helper function only errors back and no more values. For example, if I fetch the value directly: var a = array[value].color; return a; => error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes it more challenging to help you because you haven't formatted the code in your example (your Handlebars template doesn't even contain any handlebars, `{}`!).

However, as I alluded to in my comment, you should be using the [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) helper in order to lookup values on an object.

Your use-case will require two lookups: first to lookup the item from the `Strang` array based on the index provided at each `Card`'s `strangNo` (presumably). Secondly, you will need to lookup the `color` property on the returned `Strang`. Handlebars allows you to nest lookup using [subexpressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions).

Your template becomes:

```
{{#each Card}}
    {{lookup (lookup ../Strang strangNo) 'color'}}
{{/each}}
```

No helper required.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/kqjs1ez4/) for your reference.

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much, 76484! It's really great how much work you do to help me. Thank you. Thanks for the fiddle... And there it gets kinda weird. i filled the fiddle once with my original objects and adapted your "each lookup" loop. In the fiddle IT WORKS! - but not on my website. Nothing appears there ... ;-(
{{!-- Papierkorb --}}
<div class="papierkorbbereich">
  
{{#each myDoc.karte}}
    {{@index}}
    >{{lookup (lookup ../handlungsstrang strang) 'farbe'}}<
 {{/each}}
</div>

result: 1><2><3>< …

Comment: @marlowe: I can't know what the problem is without seeing the data you are passing to your template.

Comment: i've add the data and more infos above in my question. I'm a newby on stackoverflow. Sorry if I'm doing something wrong. It's still all a bit strange here on the portal.

Comment: @marlowe: Your `myDoc.karte` part is changing the context. I think you should use `@root` as in `@root/myDoc/handlungsstrang`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/rxvbjo4z/

Comment: HA!!!! You are absolutely brilliant! **THANK YOU!** The @root has made the breakthrough. IT WORKS!  Thank you so much for your efforts and time! I couldn't have done this on my own. Thank you.